# Critical discussion: Gene expression and systems biology allows us to understand the control of complex traits

Tags: gene-expression, systems-biology, gene

I'm having a bit of trouble tackling this question. Any help on what I should write about or the points I should mention would be much appreciated. I keep seeing articles about eQTL and QTL are these relevant as well?

Comment: What should be the question's title, is it theoretically or what?

Comment: In your question's current form, it may not receive many answers. 
Please take a look at our [homework policy faq](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/266/homework-policy-for-faq). 
Here you will find information on how to improve your homework question so your 
fellow users will be more inclined to help. Thank you.

Comment: @ FloriOn it is Critically discuss

Comment: @cagliari2005 thank you im havin a look at the policy now

Comment: what's eQTL? Expression quantitative trait loci?

Comment: yes its Expression quantitative trait loci?

Answer (score -3):

Turns to be too long for a comment.

If you are looking for explanation of the title/question, than it is following (roughly).

If we get information about gene expression from all different cell types, and extract also interactions between those genes (if *a* gets higher then *b* gets lower), this will allow studying multigene traits. E.g., life quality, height, mental disabilities, cardiovascular risks etc. Thing is that for most health problems that stem from single gene variation we already know named gene, or can easily find it out.

More complex issues are often hidden in statistics, links are not so clear. So, for example, autism is described by genetic variations (so far) only in less than 30% of cases or so. In other cases there is no genetic predisposition or strong evidence. Mainly that is so because many genes interact to produce final trait or illness. Looking with microscope one gene at a time will not provide information about it.

You should look into multi-gene traits, maybe pick your favourite illness (e.g. autism) and see how it is hereditary (tip: not fully). Whole-genome sequencing is important tool in tracing such issues because it gives wide overview and *a lot* of genetic information about patient.

Comment: "Looking with microscope one gene at a time will not provide information about it." Never saw a gene under a microscope. You should rephrase that to something like: "Studying one gene at the time will ..."

Comment: @cagliari2005 [metaphor](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+metaphor)